# How to have code toggle between on and off states depending on current state?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nfc, spotify, spotipy

Apologies for the title I am not really sure exactly what the name of what I am looking for is.

I have an NFC reader that accesses Spoti py and the Spotify Web API. I wish to use the same NFC card to toggle shuffle on/off.

```
if (uid == 123456789):
     sp.shuffle(state=True, device_id=DEVICE_ID)
```

The code above will turn shuffle on however when I now scan the card again I want it to disable shuffle. Essentially needing the code to read 'if card 123456789 is scanned turn shuffle on, however if shuffle is already on turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe assign state to `state` variable, and for every scan change the state by using `not`:

```
state = False

while scanning:
    if (uid == 123456789):
        state = not state
        sp.shuffle(state=state, device_id=DEVICE_ID)
```

Answer (score -1):

if the current boolean state is available (for example under sp.shuffle) i would rather do like:

```
if (uid == 123456789):
     sp.shuffle(state=!sp.shuffle, device_id=DEVICE_ID)
```

In this way you always force it to change to the opposite boolean state.

Comment: Did you try this? Just wondering because that's not valid Python which is the language tagged in the question

Comment: yes dude this is python.. very basic python

Comment: It will not work mainly due to a syntax error. What do you think the (syntactically incorrect) expression *!sp.shuffle* is going to do?

Comment: that is what i'm tryin to tell you..  of course this doesn't work because i don'tknow where the spotipy client class hold the state attributes but if you do you can reverse its value by using the exclamation mark and you get a far more elegant toggle behaviour. Btw, i don't want to argue on that

Comment: Exclamation mark is **not** a Python operator